# Python Is Not In Array Not Working

Tags: python, arrays

I have a loop that gets company names, stores them in a array. Although sometimes the company name is posted twice and I dont want to write to the file.

I check if the name is not in the array but It always returns false even if I print out the array all the values are there.

```
if phone != None:
    websiteArr.append(companyName)
    #print(websiteArr)
    if companyName not in websiteArr:
        f.write(re.sub('\s+',' ',str(companyName)) + ',' + phone.lstrip())
        print(companyName)
        companyName = ''
        phone = ''
    else:
        print('errorr')
        print(websiteArr)
else:
    continue
```

Comment: You just *put* the companyName in the list, so of course it's going to be in the list. (If you're saying it's still not in the list even then, you're going to have to show us a [mcve].)

Comment: Ya it should be, but always returns false.

Comment: you are adding `companyName` to the `websiteArr` and then checking for its non-existence in the `if` condition. So, it will be always `False`

Comment: So when you say "always returns false", you mean it always executes the `else` portion?  i.e. it prints "errorr" and the array contents?

Comment: @yklsga checking for not existence, (if not exist) that returns true

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, always returns the 'error', even tho its clearly added.

Comment: A `not in` check for something that *is* in the list is going to return `False`. Why would you expect otherwise?

Comment: @user2357112 Because I dont want to add duplicates so if its not in the list, continue to write to file, else skip

Comment: don't `append` the item until *after* you've checked for existence. Or, use a dictionary instead of a list.

Comment: But it's *in* the list. **You just put it there.**

Comment: @Pegasus but isn't companyName just added to the list before the check? So the condition would always be False, isn't it?

Comment: But you _just added it to the list_, so __of course__ it will be there.  Perhaps you want to take the `websiteArr.append(companyName)` line and move it inside the `if not in` part?

Comment: @user2357112 Don't you get it. This LOOPS though, there are MULTIPLE companyNames the same. If its not in the list, it returns true and adds to the file.

Comment: The second line of your code says "add companyName to my array".  The fourth line of your code says "if companyName is not in my array, do this stuff".  That _can never be true_, because _you just added it_.

Comment: @JohnGordon I believe you are right. Pegasus need to append it to the list after the check. So that you do not have duplicates in the list

Comment: Sorry! programming for 16h striaght fried my logic, literally had to put it after. Time for bed.

Comment: Yeah, contrary to the stereotypes, sleep is critical for programming. Get some rest.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't append the item to the list until *after* you've checked whether it exists in the list:

```
        if phone:
            #print(websiteArr)
            if companyName not in websiteArr:
                websiteArr.append(companyName)
                f.write(re.sub('\s+',' ',str(companyName)) + ',' + phone.lstrip())
                print(companyName)
                companyName = None
                phone = None
            else:
                print('errorr')
                print(websiteArr)
        else:
            continue
```

Or, use a dictionary:

```
websites = dict()
...
if phone:
    websites[companyName] = phone.lstrip()
```

You'll notice I didn't bother checking for existence, because python dictionary key/value pairs can be created lazily, that means if you refer to a key during an assignment statement, even if it doesn't (yet) exist, it will exist.

Above is equivalent to:

```
websites.add(companyName, phone.lstrip())
```

Except the `add` method will raise an error if the key exists already, whereas the lazy method simply overwrites the existing key/value pair on assignment. For fetching values, you may need to check for existence of a key unless you're iterating the tuple key/value pair.

```
for company,phone in websites.iteritems()
    f.write(re.sub('\s+',' ', company) + ',' + phone())
```

Comment: _if you refer to a key, even if it doesn't (yet) exist, it will exist_ This is true for **assigning** values, but not for **fetching** values.

Comment: Cheers @JohnGordon I'll clarify. A `DefaultDict` can help with fetching values, but that's out of scope :)